# I can't type any text into an input-field using materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I used some basic code from materialize itself, but it seems I can't type any text into an inputfield.

CDN links for js and materialize css are already included

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"/>

<div class="input-field col s6">
   <input id="eventName" type="text">
   <label for="eventName">Name of event</label>
</div>
```

Comment: can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/gcp20mxk/

Comment: I don't see why this input field is not working in my project.. I have exactly the same scripts imported as you, is there any other reason it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. I suppose some other hidden element in your project is overlapping on top of it. Are you able to focus the input field? If not, try adding the below code to your css.

```
.input-field{
  z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had a similar issue and found a solution.

I noticed that when clicking on the label in any inactive input field, the label would not move upwards out of the way.  It would block access to enter anything into the input field but if I clicked in that same input field somewhere that **wasn't** on the label, the label would move out of the way.

If you have that issue, the solution is to add an ID on the input field that matches the `for` attribute on the label:

```
<!-- this wont work -->
<div class="col s12 input-field">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
  <label for="username">Username</label>
</div>

<!-- this will -->
<div class="col s12 input-field">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
  <label for="username">Username</label>
</div>
```